# How do I set my django view's URL to the root domain of my website?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm hosting my Django app on Heroku and my domain name is registered with Network Solutions.  When I enter my domain name, i.e. www.example.com, Heroku displays:

```
"Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server."
```

I then have to navigate to the template's URL that displays my app's landing page, www.example.com/shipment/.

How can I get my root domain www.example.com to automatically redirect to www.example.com/shipment/, or alternatively, change the URL of /shipment/ to my root domain?

Here's the urls.py for my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from shipment import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.landing, name='landing'),
    url(r'^create-subscription/$', views.createSubscription, name='createSubscription'), #
    url(r'^(?P<subscription_duration>\d+)/create-account/$', views.createAccount,     name='createAccount'),
    url(r'^create-account/pay/$', views.pay, name='pay'),
    url(r'^create-account/confirm/$', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
)
```

Here's the urls.py for my project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'subscription.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^subscription/', include('subscription.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^shipment/', include('shipment.urls', namespace = "shipment")),    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: What if you prepent `url(r'^$', 'shipment.urls.landing', name='landing'),` to your project urls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed:

```
url(r'^shipment/', include('shipment.urls', namespace = "shipment")),
```

to

```
url(r'^', include('shipment.urls', namespace = "shipment")),
```

and that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

> url(r'^shipment/', include('shipment.urls', namespace = "shipment")),

It means "include all these URLs but they must start with "shipment/".

You could add a line to your site's urls.py like:

> url(r'^$', generic.RedirectView(url='/shipment/', permanent=False)),

(and then also put a corresponding "from django.views import generic" at the top of your file).

This map your URL / to a redirect view that redirects to /shipment/.